# How to name new file (string concatenation)?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to make and write in new file using `open('file.txt','w')`. But I want to give name to this file using some string from program. E.g. I have variable `s = 'new_file'`. and I want this new file has name `new_file.txt`.

Comment: Does the content for the `s` variable have to come from user input or something else?

Comment: No no. I make loop and I want to make different files by using some names from another file

Answer (score 0):

Just give the `open` function the path of the file to create by passing the variable as the first argument:

```
files_to_create = ['salt', 'pepper', 'cumin']
for i in files_to_create:
    with open('{0}.txt'.format(i), 'w') as fh:
        fh.write('this is the file for {0}\n'.format(i))
        fh.close()
```

The above creates files named `salt.txt`, `pepper.txt`, and `cumin.txt` with the given sentence in each.